# Pig Latin Translator Infinite Loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, infinite-loop

I have been working on this Pig Latin Translator and I am just about done except for the fact that these two (same) while loops are not performing as expected. When I try to put in an phrase to translate, such as "My name is" it should come out as "yMay amenay isway." The issue is that the indicated loops are performing infinitely for a reason that I am not aware of. Otherwise I have tested to make sure this code is working properly. I am not sure how to make it work. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PigLatin
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.print("Please enter a phrase to translate: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();  
    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
    int period = words.length;
    int spaces = (period - 1);
    String[] word = Arrays.copyOfRange(words,0,spaces);
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
    {
        String a = word[i].substring(0,1);
        int b = a.length();
        int c = word[i].length();
        while (b <= 4) //start of thought problem
        {
            if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
            {
                a = word[i].substring(0,b);
                b = b + 1;
                }
            } // end of thought problem
        if (word[i].startsWith("a") || word[i].startsWith("e") || word[i].startsWith("i") || word[i].startsWith("o") || word[i].startsWith("u"))
        {
            System.out.print(word[i] + "way");
            }
        else if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
        {
            String answer = word[i].substring(b,c);
            System.out.print(answer + a + "ay");
            }
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
    String end = "";
    for (String endArray: Arrays.copyOfRange(words,spaces,period))
    {
        end = end + endArray;
        }
    String z = end.substring(0,1);
    int x = z.length();
    int y = end.length();
    while (x <= 4) //start of thought problem
    {
        if (!(z.contains("a") || z.contains("e") || z.contains("i") || z.contains("o") || z.contains("u")))
        {
            z = end.substring(0,x);
            x = x + 1;
            }
        } //end of thought problem
    if (end.startsWith("a") || end.startsWith("e") || end.startsWith("i") || end.startsWith("o") || end.startsWith("u"))
    {
        System.out.print(end + "way");
        }
    else if (!(z.contains("a") || z.contains("e") || z.contains("i") || z.contains("o") || z.contains("u")))
    {
        String answer = end.substring(x,y);
        System.out.print(answer + z + "ay");
        }
    System.out.print(".");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong? What is expected and current output?

Comment: The expected output is to have a translation to Pig Latin. What I want from these loops is to have a && z to be assigned to the consonant or consonant group of each individual word. The current output is nothing, just endless execution.

Comment: LOL, I think @AdamSiemion can read ;).  He's asking you to provide some sample input (eg. `my name is adam`) and what you expect as output (eg. `y-may ame-nay is-way`).

Comment: Make your logic do exactly what you've just described. You shouldn't really need loops

Answer (score 1):

Your code is awfully formatted, here it is extracted into methods and with some variables renamed. I still haven't fixed any bugs and the renaming could be expanded.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PigLatin
{
  String[] GetWords()
  {
    System.out.print("Please enter a phrase to translate: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();  
    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
    int period = words.length;
    int spaces = (period - 1);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(words,0,spaces);
  }

  bool ContainsVowel(String text)
  {
    return text.contains("a") || text.contains("e") || text.contains("i") || text.contains("o") || text .contains("u")
  }

  bool StartsWithVowel(String text)
  {
    return text.startsWith("a") || text.startsWith("e") || text.startsWith("i") || text.startsWith("o") || text.startsWith("u")
  }

  String PigLatin(String text)
  {
    String prefix = text.substring(0,1);
    int b = a.length();
    int c = text.length();
    while (b <= 4) //start of thought problem
    {
        if (!ContainsVowel(prefix))
        {
            prefix= text.substring(0,b);
            b = b + 1;
        }
    } // end of thought problem
    if (StartsWithVowel(text)
    {
        return text + "way";
    }
    else if (!ContainsVowel(prefix))
    {
        String answer = text.substring(b,c);
        return answer + prefix + "ay";
    }
    return " ";
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    String[] words = GetWords();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        String translation = PigLatin(words[i]);
        System.out.print(translation + " ");
    }

    String end = "";
    for (String endArray: Arrays.copyOfRange(words,spaces,period))
    {
        end = end + endArray;
    }

    String z = end.substring(0,1);
    int x = z.length();
    int y = end.length();
    while (x <= 4) //start of thought problem
    {
        if (!ContainsVowel(z))
        {
            z = end.substring(0,x);
            x = x + 1;
        }
    } //end of thought problem

    if (StartsWithVowel(end))
    {
        System.out.print(end + "way");
    }
    else if (!ContainsVowel(z))
    {
        String answer = end.substring(x,y);
        System.out.print(answer + z + "ay");
    }
    System.out.print(".");
  }
}
```

This should help a lot with your logic. It's much more readable and I can begin to understand what you're trying to do.

There is a lot you can improve upon. The first thing I would do is move the `if (StartsWithVowel(end))` to the start of the `PigLatin(String text)` method. That way you don't do extra work or enter loops based one faulty assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you format your code

```
while (b <= 4) //start of thought problem
{
    System.out.println("Watch this never end"); //Add this print line
    if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
    {
        a = word[i].substring(0,b);
        b = b + 1;
    }
 }
```

same goes for

```
while (x <= 4) //start of thought problem
{
    if (!(z.contains("a") || z.contains("e") || z.contains("i") || z.contains("o") || z.contains("u")))
    {
        z = end.substring(0,x);
        x = x + 1;
    }
}
```

As you can see if you never get in that if statement you never get out of this while loop. Try using a for loop instead.

```
for(int b = a.length(); b <=4; b++)
```

Comment: What is different here from what I had?

Comment: Absolutely nothing...but you should be able to see that from the code that if never never get inside the if statements the b or x value is never increment thus in infinite loop

Comment: Ok well how would I fix that infinite loop?

Comment: I could really use your input, thanks!