# Why does this go into an infinite loop? (Pig Latin)

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, infinite-loop

I have been working on this Pig Latin Translator and I am just about done except for the fact that these two (same) while loops are not performing as expected. When I try to put in an phrase to translate, such as "My name is" it should come out as "yMay amenay isway." The issue is that the indicated loops are performing infinitely for a reason that I am not aware of. Otherwise I have tested to make sure this code is working properly. I am not sure how to make it work. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PigLatin
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.print("Please enter a phrase to translate: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();  
    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
    int period = words.length;
    int spaces = (period - 1);
    String[] word = Arrays.copyOfRange(words,0,spaces);
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
    {
        String a = word[i].substring(0,1);
        int b = a.length();
        int c = word[i].length();
        while (b <= 4) //start of thought problem
        {
            if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
            {
                a = word[i].substring(0,b);
                b = b + 1;
                }
            } // end of thought problem
        if (word[i].startsWith("a") || word[i].startsWith("e") || word[i].startsWith("i") || word[i].startsWith("o") || word[i].startsWith("u"))
        {
            System.out.print(word[i] + "way");
            }
        else if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
        {
            String answer = word[i].substring(b,c);
            System.out.print(answer + a + "ay");
            }
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
    String end = "";
    for (String endArray: Arrays.copyOfRange(words,spaces,period))
    {
        end = end + endArray;
        }
    String z = end.substring(0,1);
    int x = z.length();
    int y = end.length();
    while (x <= 4) //start of thought problem
    {
        if (!(z.contains("a") || z.contains("e") || z.contains("i") || z.contains("o") || z.contains("u")))
        {
            z = end.substring(0,x);
            x = x + 1;
            }
        } //end of thought problem
    if (end.startsWith("a") || end.startsWith("e") || end.startsWith("i") || end.startsWith("o") || end.startsWith("u"))
    {
        System.out.print(end + "way");
        }
    else if (!(z.contains("a") || z.contains("e") || z.contains("i") || z.contains("o") || z.contains("u")))
    {
        String answer = end.substring(x,y);
        System.out.print(answer + z + "ay");
        }
    System.out.print(".");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the increment to b should be outside of the if statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: The 4 is because of 4 consonants in a row at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Basically I want this loop to find the consonant or consonant group at the beginning of the the individual words in word[i] or end (which is one word) and assign it in String a.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pig Latin Translator Infinite Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840279/pig-latin-translator-infinite-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (x <= 4) // start of thought problem
        {
            if (!(z.contains("a") || z.contains("e") || z.contains("i")
                    || z.contains("o") || z.contains("u"))) {
                z = end.substring(0, x);                
            }
            x = x + 1;
        }
```

if you move your `x = x + 1;` out of **if** statement your while loop will get terminated.

Answer (score 0):

In both loops, if the `if` condition is `false`, then the `while` loop variable is never incremented. Voilà! Infinite loop.

I haven't reversed engineered your logic, but you probably want to increment the loop variables (`b` and `x`) each time through the loop, not just when the `if` condition is satisfied.

Comment: String a = word[i].substring(0,1);
        int b = a.length();
        int c = word[i].length();
        while (b <= 4) //start of thought problem
        {
            b = b + 1;
            if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
            {
                a = word[i].substring(0,b);
                }
            } // end of thought problem

Comment: Basically I want this loop to find the consonant or consonant group at the beginning of the the individual words in word[i] or end (which is one word) and assign it in String a.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that this `if` statement's body won't run enough times for the `while` loop to exit.:

```
if (!(z.contains("a") || z.contains("e") || z.contains("i") || z.contains("o") || z.contains("u")))
```

So as long as `z` contains a vowel, you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: I added x = x + 1 to eventually make z not contain a vowel, so why doesn't it exit?